# Is there an SE site for social, non-workplace communication and etiquette?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

As the title says, is there an SE site for social, non-workplace communication and etiquette? Essentially something like the topics often found on workplace.se (and sometimes academia.se), but outside of the workplace / academics. Questions about (possibly) cultural-specific behavior (but somewhat outside the bounds of travel.se) in social situations, primarily formal but also casual.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** since 18 August 2017, [Interpersonal Skills](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills/visit) has been opened to public.

---

<s>As of current, I couldn't find any graduated & public-beta sites about *social, non-workplace communication and etiquette*.</s>

However, when I searched for ["social" in Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=social&page=1&returnTitle=All+Proposals), this is what I got:

- [**Interpersonal Skills**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills) - for the life skills we use every day to communicate and interact with other people.
- [**Social Relationships**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77052/social-relationships) (**closed**) - for answers for questions involving spouse/girlfriend/boyfriend, family, friends and relationships. How to handle problems that may occur between friends and family members. Also for relationship advice and motivations.
- [**Social Conventions**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75504/social-conventions) (**deleted**) - for people who need help with how to respond in certain situations as well as raising awareness amid people on how to communicate without any issues [Concerning talking to the deaf and blind etc.]
- [**Ethics**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75061/ethics) (**deleted**)- for people interested in the social contract, cultural and commonly accepted rules, and in the roots of ethics.

Comment: Looks like SE can't be social... :)

Answer (score 2):

Great news, the site got created, and generates great content:

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com

*[Proposal page of the site, including some statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills)*

It is a shame that a lot of great questions get lost every time a proposal is deleted. A fraction of them can be scavenged from the Internet Archive:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20151214031101/http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86480/etiquette (was viable but got deleted after 7 months)
- http://web.archive.org/web/20150906203854/http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77052/social-relationships
- http://web.archive.org/web/20150906200914/http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75504/social-conventions
- http://web.archive.org/web/20150404094820/http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75061/ethics